# Как конвертировать байты в мегабайты ( на примере видеокарты)?

Tags: .net

```
  ManagementObjectSearcher Vd = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", "SELECT * FROM Win32_VideoController");

    ManagementObjectCollection Video = Vd.Get();
                foreach (ManagementObject w in Video)
                {
                    string gpuTotalMem = String.Format("{0} ", w["AdapterRam"]);
                    if (w["Caption"] != null)
                    StringBild.AppendFormat("Ваша Видеокарта: {0}  -  {1} [Bytes]", w["Caption"], gpuTotalMem);
                }
```

На выходе получаю такое:

`Ваша Видеокарта: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 860M 2147483648 [Bytes]`

Как перевести в `MB`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сдвинуть на 20 бит вправо:

```
uint MB = Convert.ToUInt32("2147483648") >> 20; // 2048
uint GB = Convert.ToUInt32("2147483648") >> 30; // 2
```

Однако следует понимать, что нехватка одного исходного байта обрежет целый ГБ:

```
uint MB = Convert.ToUInt32("2147483647") >> 20; // 2047
uint GB = Convert.ToUInt32("2147483647") >> 30; // 1
```

Сдвиг на каждые десять бит вправо эквивалентен целочисленному делению на 1024.
Причина этому следующая:

- сдвиг на 1 бит - это целочисленное деление на 2 (двоичная система счисления)
- 1024 = 2^10

Answer (score 1):

Делить на 1024^2 надо для перевода в Мб

Comment: Типа такого: `Convert.ToDouble(w["AdapterRam"]) / 1024,2` ?

Comment: @ArteS а почему бы вам не попробовать?

Comment: Я попробовал, но результата нету! Как правильнее?

Comment: @ArteS Правильнее как написано: делить на 1024 в квадрате.

Comment: @ArteS использовать калькулятор для проверки вам религия не позволяет?

Comment: Проблема решена: `/ (1024 * 1024)`